# What word could you use to approach your friend in Chinese with?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

Either close friends, family friends or fun/casual friends. E.g. "hey ... (close/family/fun friend), what are you up to?" I am looking for a word to replace the "close/family/fun friend" with.

Answer (score 2):

Words you could use to approach your friends in Chinese with are:

老爸 (lao ba) for a dad or 老妈 (lao ma) for a mom. 老兄 (lao xiong) and 老哥 (lao ge) for older male persons and 老姐 (lao jie) for an older female person. 老弟 (lao di) for a younger male person and 老妹 (lao mei) for a younger female person.
In all of the mentioned examples, 老 (lao) doesn't mean old. Its closest English equivalent might be "dear". As in "dear ((younger)(fe)male) friend", "dear mother" etc.

Another way for approaching a good friend with whom one shares a lot of interests is 好小子 (hao xiao zi), which is an expression used irrespective of age.

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was a bit ambiguous, so I edited it to make it more clear what I was actually asking.

Comment: The OP asks for a word to approach his friends with, not for an ice-breaker sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use their name - or if you really are close to them probably their nickname.

If it's family you probably need to use their position in the family relative to you 'name'.

More general things:
哥们儿：for friends
朋友：for friends
亲家：for the in laws

Edit: just wanna add 老兄: for friend (you'll sound pretty awesome if you call your friend (male of course - hence the whole 兄 thing going on over there) this).

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could also mention pinyin forms

Comment: @user3306356 - If you say 兄 (xiong, 1st tone) is an awesome way to address your friend with, could you evaluate why that is? Also, I looked up the direct meaning of 兄 which is elder brother, so obviously we are curious to know whether this can only be said to an older friend?

Comment: sorry maybe it wasnt clear it's 老兄 together - it means like 'chap' or 'dude' :: irregardless of age